# What is an easy way to track where traffic coming to my website originates from in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-7, traffic

I am using apache 2.2 on windows-7 and would like to know when traffic comes to my website, where the clicks are originating from.  What is an easy way to do this with Apache v2.2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the easiest ways is to use a log analyser like [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) or [Analog](http://www.analog.cx/). You can also use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) if you don't want to process the logs. Google Analytics is probably one of the most popular ways of doing this now.